# Adding json as params to shortcode

Tags: plugins, shortcode

First apologies if this is a stupid question I can imagine there is an easy way to do this but would like to ask anyhow.

I have setup a js framework that I am trying to integrate into a WordPress plugin. Currently if works like this.

```
example("div").media({
            plugins: {
                modal : true
            },
            options : {
                opts: 1
            }
        });
```

I am not sure how to set this up with shortcode without having hundreds of params.

```
[example div="div" plugins="???" options="???"]
```

Can't find anything here https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Thanks

Comment: Well, do these values differ from usage to usage or are they usually all the same?

Comment: Hi @kero they differ depending on what the user's sets option one could be width each div could have a different width in a page it needs to be nested to break up the sections

Comment: Then yes, you need all these parameters. Maybe a shortcode is not the best choice, but a CPT (custom post type) with these as meta info?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a shortcode with only one attribute and that attribute could be the ID of a custom post type or the name of a site option:

```
[example id="123"]
```

## Multiple instances of the framework

If you need to have multiple instances of that js framework with different attributes, then you could create a [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and use [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) (meta-data) to save the attributes of each instance. And on the shortcode you would just [read the custom fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) of the post with that ID.

## Only one instance of the framework

If you only need one instance, you could save those attributes as an array inside options database using [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API), and the ID would be the option name. And on the shortcode you would [get_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) by that ID.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what we expect but after stringify json string and using only `'` and not to use brackets in your json like array strings. Sample of my own code:

```
[dnb_list title="Bayilerimizin Listesi" tableCaptions="{'isConcat':false,'arrayOfArrayNumbersOfFields':0,'columnCaption':'item id','isSortable':true,'sortTypeDefaultIs_Asc':true,'isSearchable':true}"]
```

PS: Don't forget to replace `'`s into `"` after getting the attr.